# How to remove or reset CSS style using JS?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I want either remove or reset a style applied on a particular DOM node using JS.

```
            node.style.webkitTransitionDuration = '5000ms';
            node.style.webkitTransformOrigin = '200px 200px';
            node.style.webkitTransform = 'rotateZ(25rad)';
```

I want to reset/set `webkitTransform` time and again on a fire of an event
 Tried like this

```
        node.style.webkitTransform = 'rotateZ(0rad)';
        node.style.webkitTransform = 'rotateZ(25rad)';
```

But its not working.

P.S. Can not use any framework.

Comment: why cant you use a framework?

Comment: @Neal: thats the part of problem statement. But if I want to use a framewrok,then which should I use and how to do in that case?

Comment: so can you remove the `PS` so i can answer with a framework and not get down voted? :-P

Comment: @Neal: I Will not vote your answer down, but how its possible otherway?

Comment: @Neal: Pls delete your Answer. It not I wanted, and don't want to vote it down.

Comment: You code works just fine in Safari. However, I'd suggest using square bracket notation to avoid any naming conflicts. Ex: `node.style['webkitTransform'] = null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that should fit your needs. It toggles when you click on the document. Note: it of course only works in Webkit-based browsers.

```
animateNode(document.getElementById("test"), "5000ms", "200px 200px", "rotateZ(25rad)");
var toggle = toggleValue();
function animateNode(node, duration, origin, transform)
{
    node.style['webkitTransitionDuration'] = duration;  
    node.style['webkitTransformOrigin'] = origin;  
    node.style['webkitTransform'] = transform;
}

function toggleValue() {
    var num = 1;
    return function ()
    {
       return ++num;
    };
}

document.onclick = function()
{
    var toggleNum = toggle();
    if(toggleNum % 2 === 0)
    {
        animateNode(document.getElementById("test"), "5000ms", "200px 200px", "rotateZ(0rad)");  
    }else if(toggleNum % 2 === 1)
    {
        animateNode(document.getElementById("test"), "5000ms", "200px 200px", "rotateZ(25rad)"); 
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GdGw7/3/

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to remove the rule from the element then this should work:

```
node.style.webkitTransform = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you **don't** want to use a framework. but if it is OK (according to your comment) to do so:

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

so you can do in jQuery:

```
$('selector').css({
   webkitTransitionDuration = '5000ms',
   webkitTransformOrigin = '200px 200px',
   webkitTransform = 'rotateZ(25rad)'
})
```

you can clear out the style element with:

```
$('selector').attr('style','');
```

add class:

```
$('selector').addClass('newClass');
```

remove class:

```
$('selector').removeClass('rClass');
```

Comment: I need to remove/reset CSS,I need not to apply CSS.

Comment: so change the selector however you want ^_^